# Shall I/How to Repair Falling Subfloor?

Tags: flooring, framing, structural, joists, subfloor

I happened to find the one piece subfloor under my dishwasher is falling. Shall I repair it? If yes, how to do that? The most professional way I suppose is to remove the cabinet and floor in the kitchen and replace the whole piece, but it would take too much time and money. Any workaround?

Please ignore the wet wood, it was caused by a dishwasher leak, and has been taken care of already.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Jasen The OP mentioned that the leak has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subfloor does many things for the structure of the house: it ties all of the joist together, adds structural stability against major forces working against the house, provides a flat surface upon which to nail the finish layer of flooring (the thing you actually step on), and many other things.

If only one piece of one board is missing or damaged, the structure of the house will not suffer, as there are many structural redundancies built into the structure of the house, ie if all it took was a missing piece of subfloor to destabilize a house, you'd see a lot of crumbling structures around you.

There is only one reason why you'd want to replace a single piece of board, and that is if it's directly below a piece of finished floor with heavy traffic and has a weak type of flooring material, e.g. a piece of flooring only covered by a vinyl plank. In that case, you'd experience a soft spot in the floor. But for a piece that is not stepped on because it's under the dishwasher, this does not matter.

For all of this, I recommend that just ignore it. You will gain nothing by replacing just that piece.